# Best settings to capture lightning on a D3100?

Tags: nikon, lighting, dslr, nikon-d3100

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What technique and settings should I use to capture lightning strikes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/what-technique-and-settings-should-i-use-to-capture-lightning-strikes)

Quick, I need some help. I am trying to get some pictures of the storm thats going on right now and was trying to figure out some good settings. I first tried to shoot at 25" and F5.3 is that to much or to little? Also what about the ISO where should that be at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one ideal setting, it all depends on the ambient lighting. You'll need to do a couple of sample shots to see how the shots are coming out and adjust accordingly. You might as well set your ISO to 200 to begin with though, the less noise the better.

Comment: I am pretty sure this type of photography needs a tripod, bulb (long exposure) mode and  shutter cable / remote.

Comment: Yup. I assume as he has already tried 25" exposures he's already got at least a tripod.